# Rotation of UIPageViewController in Container View Controller

Tags: containers, uipageviewcontroller, screen-rotation

I have a UIViewController that contains other ViewControllers. Initial ViewController is set in viewDidLoad:

```
FirstViewController *first = [FirstViewController alloc] init];
first.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
first.view.frame = m_content.frame;

[self addChildViewController:first];
[m_content.view addSubview:first.view];
[first didMoveToParentViewController:self];
m_activeViewController = first;
```

This Container Controller has implemented **automaticallyForwardAppearanceAndRotationMethodsToChildViewControllers** to return YES. It has also implemented to manualy forward rotation changes to non active ViewControllers

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    for(UIViewController *vc in m_viewControllers)
    {
        if(vc != [m_activeViewController]
            [vc willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
    }
}
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    for(UIViewController *vc in m_viewControllers)
    {
        if(vc != [m_activeViewController]
            [vc didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:fromInterfaceOrientation];
    }
}
```

When menu button is tapped i make the transition between ViewControllers.

```
- (void)onMenuItemTapped:(id)sender
{
    UIViewController *vc = [m_viewControllers objectAtIndex:sender.tag];

    vc.view.frame = m_content.frame;
    [self addChildViewController:vc];
    [self transitionFromViewController:m_activeViewController toViewController:vc duration:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:nil completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [m_activeViewController removeFromParentViewController];
    m_activeViewController = vc;
    }];
}
```

This transition works fine for my "normal" ViewControllers and they are displayed properly after orientation changes, even if they are not active. However, one of these Child View Controllers, called SecondCV, has **UIPageViewController** as a Child View Controller. I have **UIPageViewControllerDelegate** and **UIPageViewControllerDataSource** set to this SecondCV and in **pageViewController:spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:** I return UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin for Portrait and UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid for Landscape. Rotation for this SecondVC works correctly when its active - there are two pages on the landscape and one on the portrait mode displayed correctly. But when this SecondVC is not active the rotation is incorrect. Even if **pageViewController:spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:** is called, there is still one page in both Portrait and Landscape mode. I am trying to fix this for some time, but i dont see any other options. Do you have any ideas how to fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this kind of tricky.

Actually the SecondVC was rotated correctly, or at least, spine location was changed correctly. So when I have rotated the device and the SecondVC was not active view controller in parent view, it **HAS** received rotation messages and **pageViewController:spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:** was called also. I set the correct spine location for new interface orientation and called **setViewControllers** to SecondVC's page view controller. Problem was, that even if i set two view controller for **UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid**, after displaying SecondVC there was still just one, like in UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin.

I have "fixed" the problem, by setting view controllers to page view controller in **viewWillAppear:** again, because when this method is called, spine location for page view controller is correct and based on this information i set one, or two pages (view controllers)

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
if(m_pageController.spineLocation == UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid)
{
    LeftPageController *left;
    RightPageController *right;
    if(m_pageController.viewControllers.count > 0)
    {
        left = [m_pageController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

        right = [m_storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rightPage"];
        [right loadView];
    }

    [m_pageController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:left, right, nil] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward | UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:NO completion:nil];

    [m_left hideGallery];
}

if(m_pageController.spineLocation == UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin)
{

    [m_pageController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[m_pageController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward | UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:NO completion:nil];
}

[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}


- (UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation))
{
    LeftPageController *left = [pageViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    [pageViewController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:left] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward | UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:NO completion:nil];

    pageViewController.doubleSided = NO;     

    return UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin;
}

if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation))
{    
    LeftPageController *left;
    RightPageController *right;
    if(pageViewController.viewControllers.count > 0)
    {
        left = [pageViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        right = [m_storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"rightPage"];
        [right loadView];
    }

    [pageViewController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:left,right, nil] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward | UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse animated:NO completion:nil];

    return UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid;
}

return UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin;
}
```

I know i am doing the same thing twice, but thats the price i am willing to pay in this case. Why after calling **pageViewController:spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:** and setting two view controllers for Landscape, when SecondVC is inactive, is only one ViewController in m_pageController in **viewWillAppear:** after activating SecondVC stays a mystery for me.

Comment: I am using page view controller too, and i have added VC's to an array, but don't know the proper way of transitioning various VC's, how can i move to next VC's using page curl transition. Can you please guide me for that or post some sample code of it.

Comment: [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) I think you can find everythink here, if not, contact me

Comment: I haven't got any solution yet, please have a look at my question if you can guide me.   "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13776894/uipageviewcontroller-change-from-two-page-mode-to-one-page-mode-without-changi#comment18942540_13776894"

Answer (score 0):

I included following code to solve this problem in iOS 6:

```
- (UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{

    NSArray *allPageControllers = pageViewController.viewControllers

    if (allPageControllers != nil) {
       [self setViewControllers:allPageControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
    }

    else {

       UIViewController *defaultViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
       [self setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:defaultViewController] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];
       [defaultViewController release];
    }

    return UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin;
}
```

Hope it helps someone!