# UIPageviewController - Change from two page mode to one page mode without changing orientation

Tags: iphone, ipad, uipageviewcontroller

I am using UIPageViewController to show two view controllers at a time. After showing a couple of such views, i want to show single view controllers without changing orientation, it is fixed to landscape. I am making in iPad.

Below is the code i am using for this:

```
-(id)initWithViewControllers:(NSMutableArray *)Controllers
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
if(self)
{
    self.VControllers =  Controllers;

    pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc]initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

    self.pageController.view.frame = CGRectMake(12.0f, 10.0f, 748.0f, 985.0f);
    self.pageController.delegate = self;
    self.pageController.dataSource = self;
    [self.pageController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[VControllers objectAtIndex:0] ] direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
     }];
    [self addChildViewController:self.pageController];
    [self.view addSubview:self.pageController.view];   
}
return self;
}

- (UIPageViewControllerSpineLocation)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
               spineLocationForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation
{
if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation))
{
 //Set the array with only 1 view controller
    UIViewController *currentViewController = [self.pageController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:currentViewController];
    [self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:NULL];

    //Important- Set the doubleSided property to NO.
    self.pageController.doubleSided = NO;
    //Return the spine location
    return UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMin;

}

else
{
NSArray *viewControllers = nil;

    exampleViewController *currentViewController = [self.pageController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];

    NSUInteger currentIndex = [self.VControllers indexOfObject:currentViewController];

    if(currentIndex == 0 || currentIndex %2 == 0)
    {
        UIViewController *nextViewController = [self pageViewController:self.pageController viewControllerAfterViewController:currentViewController];
        viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:currentViewController, nextViewController, nil];
    }
    else
    {
        UIViewController *previousViewController = [self pageViewController:self.pageController viewControllerBeforeViewController:currentViewController];
        viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:previousViewController, currentViewController, nil];
    }
    //Now, set the viewControllers property of UIPageViewController
    [self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:YES completion:NULL];

    return UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid;
}
}


 - (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
 {
int index = [self.VControllers indexOfObject:viewController];

//[self checkViewControllers];
if (index - 1 >= 0)
{
    ind = index;
    return [self.VControllers objectAtIndex:index - 1];
}
ind = index;
return nil;
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
int index = [self.VControllers indexOfObject:viewController];
//[self checkViewControllers];
if (index + 1 < [self.VControllers count])
{
    ind = index;
    return [self.VControllers objectAtIndex:index + 1];
}
ind = index;

return nil;
}
```

What i need is to show the single view controllers after shows double views a couple of time. This functionality i am unable to active yet. Can anyone guide for this .

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And...your question is...?

Comment: I want to show the single view controllers after showing double views a couple of times, without changing orientation.

Comment: Well, is there a problem with 'pushViewController' or 'addSubview'? The orientation doesn't change naturally, unless you change it personally as far as I know.

Comment: no problem with any view controller or orientation. The thing is i want to change the page view controller to one page mode from two mode. If i change screen orientation it works but i need to do it without changing orientation.

Comment: Consider using the view methods: 'setneedsLayout' and 'setneedsDisplay'. It forces the few to redraw itself, laying out the components according to properties anew. It's also what's called when you change orientation.

Comment: no solution, can you post some sample code if you have or you can.

Comment: I'm afraid not. (No Mac in reach, I only have one at work). Though, may I suggest removing the spine controller (removeFromSuperview) and adding the single view to the base view?

Comment: Please look if you can get some solution. Thanks.

Comment: Are you making use of the curl effect? Because if not then you should try to create your own container. Then you'll be in full control.

Comment: i am using page view controller to get page curl animation and getting two page mode.